# Load tab content on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tabs, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a few tabs on my website that loads as soon as the page is loaded. I do not want that. I rather want each tab-content to be loaded as soon as I press on it. I have solved this so far in the following way:

I have a tab as follows:

```
<li><a data-Toggle="tab" href="#Alarm">Larm</a></li>
```

When I press on this tab, it directs to the Alarm-div, which looks like this:

```
<div id="Alarm" class="tab-pane fade">
   <a class="alarmTab" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="LoadAlarm" asp-route-id="@Model.Plants.First().STATION">Hämta larm</a>
   <div class="larm2" id="larm2"></div>
</div>
```

Within this div, I have created a link called alarmTab, which calls an action LoadAlarm, which looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadAlarm(string id)
{
  return ViewComponent("Events", new { id = id});
}
```

I also have a JS, which presents the result from the ViewComponent within the larm2-div.

This whole procedure works. However, I want this to happen as soon as I press on the alarm-tab, without having to press on the hyperlink alarmTab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax call to the server when the tab link is clicked.

Add an html5 data attribute to the links so we can store a value indicating whether the content needed for the tab pane is already loaded.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <a class="contentLink" style="display: none;" 
         data-loaded="0"  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadAlarm" 
         asp-route-id="1">Hämta larm</a>
        <div class="content" ></div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <a class="contentLink" style="display: none;" 
           data-loaded="0"  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadAlarm"
           asp-route-id="2">Hämta larm</a>
        <div class="content" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the tab content pane is shown, read the href value generated by the link tag helper and make an ajax call if the `data-loaded` attribute value is 0. Once we get the response from the server, update the `data-loaded` value to 1 and update the inner html of the content div.

```
$(function() {

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
        var $c = $(target).find(".contentLink");
        var $content = $(target).find(".content");
        if ($c.data("loaded") === 0) {
            var url = $c.attr("href");
            $.get(url, function (r) {
                $content.html(r);
                $c.data("loaded",1);
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

You can now modify the above code to load the content for the active tab on page laod as well. The idea is same for that as well.

Comment: @Shyju This solution do work but we ran into antoher problem. We have other javascripts that doesn't work after this fix. They don't work because the DOM don't get updated (I think). When I chose "show source" from my browser the recently loaded panel don't show up in the source code, even if it show in the web browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shyju, what do you mean by "You can now modify the above code to load the content for the active tab on page laod as well. The idea is same for that as well." ?